# SASS: content block mixin (or placeholder) that takes contextual selectors and appends them to selector in mixin

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I want to do something like this:

```
@mixin context($size) {
  body.#{$size} {
    @content
  }
}

div {
  span {
    font-size: 2em;
    @include context('large') {
      & {
        font-size: 5em;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To produce:

```
div span {
  font-size: 2em;
}

body.large div span {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

What it ACTUALLY (predictably) produces:

```
div span {
  font-size: 2em;
}

div span body.large {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

I could just replicate the selectors inside different mixins, but given that selectors could be complex that's a lot of extra junk:

```
@include context('large') {
  div {
    span {
      font-size: 5em;
    }
  }
}
```

I could make the selectors into mixins so I don't have to repeat them each time, but...

Isn't there a way to use placeholders, maybe in combination with mixins, to get what I want in the first two code blocks above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to move the `&` to be part of the mixin:

```
@mixin context($size) {
  body.#{$size} & {
    @content
  }
}

div {
  span {
    font-size: 2em;
    @include context('large') {
        font-size: 5em;
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
div span {
  font-size: 2em;
}

body.large div span {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

As of Sass 3.4, you can write this to work both inside a selector and at the root of the document:

```
@mixin optional-at-root-nest($sel) {
    @at-root #{if(not &, $sel, selector-nest($sel, &))} {
        @content;
    }
}

@mixin context($size) {
    @include optional-at-root-nest('body.#{$size}') {
        @content
    }
}

div {
    span {
        font-size: 2em;
        @include context('large') {
                font-size: 5em;
        }
    }
}

@include context('large') {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: This gives me an error: "Base-level rules cannot contain the parent-selector-referencing character '&'."

Comment: Are you using the mixin outside of nested selectors as well?

Comment: That was it, a mistake from testing. Have a suggestion for cases where I might need to do that too?

Comment: Note for future readers: I had tried this with `body.#{$size} { & { @content } }` and it didn't work. Can't be nested, it appears.

Comment: Other than creating a second mixin?  I don't think there's an option here.  There are improvements coming to the parent selector, but it doesn't look like they will help this use case (see: https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/286 and https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/774).  If you want to test for yourself, some of this should be in the edge version (`gem install sass --pre`).

Comment: @glortho In case you're still interested, I've added a 3.4 solution that will cover usage for both inside and outside of a selector.