# SASS: How to declare inline browser-dependent overrides?

Tags: sass

The goal is to get final CSS to look something like:

```
.selector {
  font: 'Arial';
  font-weight: 400;
}

.ie7 .selector {
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

- The `&` selector references the parent selector, it can't reference global class.
- Can't really find a way to do it with `@extend`.
- Mixins would be the answer, but I don't know if it's possible to access the full selector itself:

  ```
  .selector {
    font: 'Arial';
    font-weight: 400;
    @include ie7 {
      font-weight: 500;
    }     
  }
  ```

Basically, I'm looking for the way of declaring a prefix selector for current selector tree. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS: content block mixin (or placeholder) that takes contextual selectors and appends them to selector in mixin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031079/sass-content-block-mixin-or-placeholder-that-takes-contextual-selectors-and-a)

Comment: There's not enough information here for this question to be useful to anyone.  Without seeing what your ie7 mixin is doing, your answer is over-engineered (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031079/sass-content-block-mixin-or-placeholder-that-takes-contextual-selectors-and-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** just just `&` to do this:

```
.selector {
  font: 'Arial';
  font-weight: 400;
  .ie7 & {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
}
```

Just write the .SCSS as `.ie7 &` and Sass will interpret that as a container:

```
.selector {
  font: 'Arial';
  font-weight: 400;
}
.ie7 .selector {
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `@at-root` along with `&` will solve this:

```css
.foo {
   .bar {
     color: blue;
     @at-root .ie7 & {
       color: red;
     }
   }
 }
```

Is compiled to:

```css
.foo .bar {
  color: blue;
}
.ie7 .foo .bar {
  color: red;
}
```